# Log4J log does not create back up files

Tags: java, logging, jvm, log4j, websphere

I have configured my application log in the generic JVM arguments of my Websphere application server as :

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:D:/app_logs/log4j/log4j.properties
```

The log4j.properties file looks like:

```
log4j.appender.app.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.app.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.app=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.app.File=D:/app_logs/log4j/logs/app.log
log4j.appender.app.MaxFileSize=8000KB
log4j.appender.app.MaxBackupIndex=10

#root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=debug,app

# restrictions
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate=info
#log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.type=debug
#log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.ps.PreparedStatementCache=debug
log4j.logger.com.abc.wm.eu.app.interop=off
log4j.logger.com.abc.wm.eu.app.webservice.servlet.ADOServlet=off

#
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis=error
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=error
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=error
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content=error
log4j.logger.org.htmlparser=error
```

**Problem:**

The log rolls over. But the back up logs are not created. The same configuration works fine for another application running on the same server.
I have no idea what is wrong here.

All suggestions and solutions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Is the non-backup log file (i.e. app.log) being created? And if so, does the file contain any content?

Comment: Thanks Victor.
app.log file does get created. And log is written to the file. The problem is when the size limit is reached, the back up files are not created.

Comment: So, if the backup files are not created, are the log messages still appending at the original log file?

My silly experience is that when I try to rollover, it does roll but backup file not created, and I found that there are two server instances running at the same time, so when I turn off one of them, the file is created successfully.

Comment: Thanks Victor
Yes there are two server instances running. But they both have different log4j configuration. They have different log4j.properties and log files.
The log file for the other server works just fine with no problems at all. Logs,rolls over and creates backup files too.

Comment: Then, I am sorry that I may not be able to help you much. What I am guessing is that, the folder of your log file has been locked by other programs so that no file can successfully be created. You may try to manually create a file on that folder when your server is running. But that's just silly suggestion, sorry about that.

Comment: @VictorWong, may I suggest you place your comment as an actual answer. Most likely you're right, it's a file locking issue. I'd also suggest using `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to see what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
```

This might do the trick